# Jxls v2.2.8 How to merged cells?

Tags: jxls

Refer to [Jxls V2.2.8 release note](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/index.html)
Newest Jxls support to merge cells, But the documentation is still older version.

Does anyone know how to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If what you need merged is static you can easily merge the cells in the template itself. Unfortunately I'm looking for the same answer for dynamic jx:each columns in Jxls V2.3 and I haven't found a solution yet - it seems they don't have this covered yet. It takes into account already merged cell as in if you add dynamic columns to the left the merged cells will be shifted to the right accordingly. Also if you put a jx:each in a cell with merged cells, it will repeat the merged cells.